# SSMS v18.10 - Open a script file with existing connection and database

Tags: ssms

In previous versions of SSMS, if I had a database selected in Object Explorer and then opened a script file through File → Recent Files, SSMS automatically used my existing connection and database. In v18.10 (build 15.0.18390.0), SSMS instead prompts me for a connection and then defaults to the master database.

Is there a setting somewhere that will make v18.10 (build 15.0.18390.0) behave like previous versions?

Comment: I just tried it in SSMS 18.9.2, it works as expected (no new connection prompt)

Comment: Updated my question. I am experiencing the issue with 18.10 (build 15.0.18390.0), which is the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled a previous version (SSMS 2016) and repaired the 18.10 install and it's behaving as normal now.